# Count lines not 0 found Textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I want to calculate the amount in a multiline Textbox where the value 0 is not found.

```
If TxtListScanValue.Text = ("2") Then
    TxtDrawR2.Text &= Environment.NewLine & lastDraw2
    Dim ListScan = TxtNumberListScan.Lines.ToList.Select(Function(o, i) New With {.scan = o, .Index = i})
    Dim DrawR2 = TxtDrawR2.Lines.ToList.Select(Function(o, i) New With {.draw = o, .Index = i})
    Dim list2 = From a In ListScan From b In DrawR2 Where a.Index = b.Index Select LstScan = a.scan, DrwR2 = ("00" & b.draw).Substring(("00" & b.draw).Length - 2) Order By DrwR2 Descending
    TxtListScanTxt.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, list2)
End If
```

If TxtdrawR5 =

```
2
4
0
0
1
3
5
```

In output I want to display: 5 because:
I want to calculate the count lines where the value 0 is not found. Count lines no have 0 value :D (2+4+1+3+5 = 5) (5 lines no have 0 value).

Comment: I don't understand your goal. are you trying to "count" the lines with values other than `0`? That is, there are 7 lines, and 5 do not have zero? Or, if you are wanting a `sum` of values, I don't understand what values you are adding. I get 15 (the sum of all lines where the value is not 0. Please clarify.

Comment: yes. 5 do not have zero. Sum lines no have 0 value :D

Comment: OK, so in computer terminology, that is _not_ a `SUM`, that is a `COUNT`: `2+4+1+3+5 DOES NOT EQUAL 5`, `2+4+1+3+5 = 15`! the `COUNT` of the rows is 5.

Comment: ok. i understand sorry for that i think learn.

Comment: No worries, but computers are extremely unforgiving about such things. So now, to your issue: what have you tried so far? You can set up a counter, then add to the count in a loop that checks each line for a value of 0. Just remember that you are lot looking for a number `0`, but a `string = "0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create function like this:

```
'For Counting
Private Function CountNonZero(ByVal TheCtrl As TextBox) As Integer
    Dim myCnt As Integer = 0
    For Each Content In TheCtrl.Lines
        Dim ContentVal As Integer = 0
        Integer.TryParse(Content, ContentVal)
        If ContentVal <> 0 Then myCnt += 1
    Next
    Return myCnt
End Function

'For Counting

Private Function SummingNonZero(ByVal TheCtrl As TextBox) As Integer
    Dim mySum As Integer = 0
    For Each Content In TheCtrl.Lines
        Dim ContentVal As Integer = 0
        Integer.TryParse(Content, ContentVal)
        If ContentVal <> 0 Then mySum += ContentVal 
    Next
    Return mySum 
End Function
```

And you can count or sum now:

```
dim TxtdrawR5Count as integer = CountNonZero(TxtdrawR5) 
dim TxtdrawR5Sum as integer = SummingNonZero(TxtdrawR5)
```

Comment: It would be better to use [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) rather than involve IsNumeric

Comment: That's not how you use TryParse.  What if it returns false? That's where the If-Block should be.

Comment: @user11982798 either way is fine *in this case* because `ContentVal` is init each time and you are checking the value of `ContentVal <> 0`... Basically you are not adding to `mySum` if it doesn't succeed. In all rightfulness, it should be used in an if statement as it *is a conditional function*...

Comment: `If Integer.TryParse(Content, ContentVal) Then mySum += ContentVal End If`

Comment: `mySum += If(Integer.TryParse(Content, ContentVal), ContentVal, 0)` would be better and you can get rid of the rest.

Comment: Read that docs. [Integer.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8)